# Proof of an inequality involving $e^x$.

Tags: calculus, inequality, derivatives

> Prove that $e^{x-1} \geq x, $ for every $x$.

I'm not allowed to use MVT or integrals, but IVT and derivatives are allowed.

I tried to define a function $f(x)=e^{x-1}-x$ and then $\,f'(x)=e^{x-1}-1$ so the function has minimum in $x=1$ where $y=0$, thus the inequality holds.

Is that good? Is there another way which does not involve derivatives?

Thanks!

Comment: The idea is good. How do you know it's a minimum though?

Comment: Second derivative is the easiest way I find.

Comment: @user88595 $f'' > 0$

Comment: @Galc127 Yes that's it. But you need to include it because if it's a maximum, then you just proved that $e^{x-1}\le x \quad \forall x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: What is "MVT"? "IVT"?

Comment: @sidht: thank you, I know... Just saying it's missing.

Comment: @Shuchang: Mean Value Theorem and Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @user88595, I wrote that it is minimum because I think it's obvious to show it after finding the critical point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bernoulli's inequality 
$$\left(1+\frac {x-1}n\right)^n\ge 1+n\frac{x-1}n=x$$
(as soon as $\frac {x-1}n\ge -1$, which is the case for almost all $n$).
In the limit the left hand side converges to $e^{x-1}$ (by defeinition, depending on the source)

Comment: Great! thank you. Do we need also to show that the left hand monotically increasing, thus smaller than the limit and therefore the inequality must hold or is it redundant?

Comment: @Galc127 If the goal is only $\ge x$ (not $>x$ for $x\ne1$) then convergence alone is enough.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is correct. Though I don't know another way, I think your way is easy to understand.

Comment: Proof of minimum missing. For what I see, his proof could also show the complete opposite!

Comment: I don't think his proof is for opposite.

Comment: "could". Not saying it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, assuming you know the exponential function is increasing.  Maybe you should mention it.  Another way, not requiring derivatives, is to note that if $x \leq 1$, then $e^{x-1} \geq e^0 = 1 \geq x$ since $\exp$ is increasing, while if $x \geq 1$, since $\ln$ is increasing, the comparison property of the definite integral gives 
$\ln(e^{x-1}) = x-1 =\int_1^x 1\,dt \geq \int_1^x 1/t\,dt = \ln x$, implying $e^{x-1}\geq x$.

Comment: Nice proof. Unfortunately, integrals are not allowed.

Comment: @Galc127 :     thx   %%%

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that a global minimum is achieved at $x=1$. This is guaranteed if $f'<0$ for $x<1$ and $f'>0$, for $x>1$.